# add_filter('query_vars') not working in custom template

Tags: wp-query, templates, page-template, query-variable

I'm trying to add a query parameter to a custom template in order to look up a record from the DB with the ID passed in.  Here's how I'm attempting to do it:

At the very top of my custom template, I add the `college_id` param to the `query_vars` filter.

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'college_id';
  return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );
```

Then, in my content lower down, I attempt to get that query variable and output it to the screen, as well as look up the record in the database.  Here's how I'm doing that:

```
$college_to_delete = $wp_query->query_vars['college_id'];
echo $college_to_delete;
echo 'query'.get_query_var('college_id');
global $wpdb;
$colleges = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * from '.$college_table.' WHERE ID='.$college_id.';');
```

The idea is that I'll grab the college_id query variable, display it to the screen, and then SELECT the record from the database whose ID matches the query ID. What am I doing wrong?  Totally new wordpress developer so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: How are you setting `college_id`? Requests are parsed long before the template is loaded, your filter should be in a plugin file or theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I can definitely try that.  I'm setting `college_id` through window.location in javascript, as I want to use a `confirm()` to make sure the user wants to delete that college.

Comment: Aha! Declaring the custom query_vars in functions.php did the trick!

Comment: please add it as an answer and accept it